# Symfony: How to create a form with a choice field of another entilty?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form that has to contain a choice field which displays its content from another entity (not the entity used in the form), so this is how I tried to create it:

```
$user = new user();
        $profils=$rep->findAll();
        $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($user,array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->add('id', 'text',array('attr'=>array("autocomplete" => "off",'name'=>'login_user','required'=>'required',
                'maxlength'=>'255','placeholder'=>'Matricule')))
            ->add('password', 'password',array('attr'=>array('autocomplete' => 'off','placeholder'=>'Mot de passe','required'=>'required')))
            ->add('profils', 'choice',[
                 'choices' => [$profils]],array('attr'=>array('mapped'=>false,'required'=>'required')))
            ->add('Ajouter', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn', 'id' => 'login_btn',
                'style' => "width:6vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;")))
            ->getForm();
```

Pleaaaase help me, as I'm new with symfony, I may be stuck in problems you may consider stupid, I'm sorry but i couldn't find a solution myself.

Comment: which version of symfony2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using symfony 2.6

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the place of  "'mapped'=>false" and it worked:

```
$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($user,array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->add('id', 'text',array('attr'=>array("autocomplete" => "off",'name'=>'login_user','required'=>'required',
                'maxlength'=>'255','placeholder'=>'Matricule')))
            ->add('password', 'password',array('attr'=>array('autocomplete' => 'off','placeholder'=>'Mot de passe','required'=>'required')))
            ->add('profils', 'choice'
                ,array( 'choices' => array('Profils' => $profArr),'mapped'=>false),
                array('attr'=>array('required'=>'required')))
            ->add('Ajouter', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn', 'id' => 'login_btn',
                'style' => "width:6vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;")))
            ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is this :

In the repository of profil entity create a method eg that return an array of profils e.g

```
class ProfilRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myFindAll()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $entites      = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

        return $entites;
    }
}
```

In the controller as you are doing now,

```
$user = new user();

// I'm asuming that Profil is an entity
$profils = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    // this should return an array
    ->getRepository('SdzBlogBundle:Profil')->myFindAll()
;

$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($user, array('csrf_protection' => false))
      ->add('id', 'text', array(
          'attr' => array(
              'autocomplete' => 'off',
              'name'         => 'login_user',
              'required'     => 'required',
              'maxlength'    => '255',
              'placeholder'  => 'Matricule'
          )
      ))
      ->add('password', 'password', array(
          'attr' => array(
              'autocomplete' => 'off',
              'placeholder'  => 'Mot de passe',
              'required'     => 'required'
          )
      ))
      ->add('profils', 'choice', array(
          'choices' => $profils,
          array(
              'attr' => array(
                  'mapped'   => false,
                  'required' => 'required'
              )
          )
      ))
      ->add('Ajouter', 'submit', array(
          'attr' => array(
              'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block rounded_btn',
              'id'    => 'login_btn',
              'style' => "width:6vw;height:5vh;padding:0px 0px; position:relative;left:5vmin;top:1vmin;font-size:2vmin;"
          )
      ))
      ->getForm()
;
```

That's all for now, Good luck.

Comment: Thaaaaanx for ur help :) but the error says that some methods of the entity 'profil' are missing in the entity 'user' which is the basic entity of the form; so i need to overcome this entity, as if i want to add an extra field in the form that doesn't exist in the entity 'user' (if it was a field with a simple type, i could user 'mapped'=>false)

Comment: This is the error : Neither the property "profils" nor one of the methods "getProfils()", "profils()", "isProfils()", "hasProfils()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\user".

Comment: check the relationship between your entities, don't forget to specify the repository on the entities

Comment: yeeees i know, and my question was : how can i make this field displays content fetched from another entity, I mean 'profils' contains the content of a database table, i want to display it in a choice field in the form

Comment: loop through it ok?

Comment: is it possible to loop in a form???? m sorry for all these questions but m new with all of this

Comment: Try something like this : {% for choice in form.$profils.vars.choices %}
{{ choice.label }}
{{ choice.value }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: It's already there by this line    ->add('profils', 'choice',[

Comment: yes but the problem is there : 'choices' => [$profils]] : that what causes the error

Comment: This is an example from symfony doc : $builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('m' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female'),
)); adapt it to your need

Comment: ok thanx for ur help :D but u didn't understand my problem. Thnx anyway ;)